# Android - start intent issues

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, classnotfoundexception

Whenewer I want to start new activity, I use this code:

```
Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(this, Info1.class);
startActivity(myIntent1);
```

But, what about the case, I am getting class name from String Array? I have tried method class.forName like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(array[1]));
startActivity(intent);
```

But no success. It is giving me error of

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Info1 in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

even though in first case it started an activity successfully. I have to add that I am 100% sure array[1] contains string "Info1" and that I have Info1.class in my package.

Do you know, how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method

```
Class.forName("xxxxx");
```

Needs fully qualified name which means you should give the name along with the package details(in which package the class exists)

as an example

```
Class.forName("com.mypackage.MyClass");
```

[Documentation Reference here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Class clazz = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().findClass(array[1]);
new Intent(this, clazz);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the full package name to your class.forName parameter, like ple instead of array[1].